# ¿Que hacer cuando un update te devuelve NULL en php?

Tags: php, update, crud

Estoy haciendo un Crud con poo y mvc. Tengo problemas al hacer el update, me retorna un NULL.

Esta es la clase donde recibo los datos y los envió al control.

```
$objEmpleado = new empleadoo($id2, $nombre, $telefono, $cargo, $email );
  
$objControlempleados = new controlempleados($objEmpleado);
$r = $objControlempleados->modificar();``
 
var_dump($r);
```

Y este es el códido del control donde esta la sentencia SQL.

```
function modificar() 
{    
    $cod=$this->objEmpleados->getId();

    $nom=$this->objEmpleados->getNombre();

    $tel=$this->objEmpleados->getTelefono();
    $car=$this->objEmpleados->getCargo();
    $ema=$this->objEmpleados->getEmail();
    $objControlConexion = new ControlConexion();
    $objControlConexion->abrirBd("localhost","root","","bdmesaayuda");
    $comandoSql = "UPDATE empleados SET nombre = '".$nom."', telefono = '".$tel."', cargo = '".$car."', email = ".$ema." where id_Empleado = '".$cod."'";
    $objControlConexion->ejecutarComandoSql($comandoSql);
    $objControlConexion->cerrarBd();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Una de las finalidades de la POO es reflejar en las clases y métodos una lógica apropiada para lo que debe hacer ese objeto, estableciendo además todos los controles adecuados. Luego, ese objeto podrá ser reutilizado en cualquier escenario donde necesitemos operar con él. Significa que vas a programar esa clase/método **una sola vez** y por tanto conviene hacerlo bien.

Cuando se analiza tu método `modificar()`, rápidamente vemos que es deficiente:

1. No tiene control de errores
2. No informa de nada. Lo menos que se espera en método como este es saber si se actualizaron registros o no.

Tu método puede y debe mejorarse, haciendo de él un método robusto. Es muy simple hacerlo:

```
function modificar() 
{    
    $cod=$this->objEmpleados->getId();

    $nom=$this->objEmpleados->getNombre();

    $tel=$this->objEmpleados->getTelefono();
    $car=$this->objEmpleados->getCargo();
    $ema=$this->objEmpleados->getEmail();
    $db = new ControlConexion();
    $db->abrirBd("localhost","root","","bdmesaayuda");
    $sql = "UPDATE empleados SET nombre = '$nom', telefono = '$tel', cargo = '$car', email = '$ema' where id_Empleado = '$cod'";
    if ( $db->ejecutarComandoSql($sql) ) 
    {
        #Convendría controlar también la cantidad de filas
        #según la API que estés usando
        $mData=array ('msg'=>'Filas actualizadas');
    } else {
        $mData=array ('error'=>'Ocurrió un error ...');
    }
    $db->cerrarBd();
    return $mData;
}
```

Si analizas el código, el método controla el éxito o error de la función. Si hay éxito devolverá un array con una clave `msg` dentro, si hay error, devolverá un array con una clave error dentro y un mensaje.

En el contexto, controlarías así:

```
$objEmpleado = new empleadoo($id2, $nombre, $telefono, $cargo, $email );
  
$objControlempleados = new controlempleados($objEmpleado);
$r = $objControlempleados->modificar();

/*Verificamos con un ternario si el método devolvió error o éxito*/
$msg=empty($r['error']) ? $r['msg'] : $r['error'];
/* Pasar $msg a la Vista para que informe al usuario*/
```

En el código he implementado algunas prácticas que te recomiendo:

1. Simplificar la consulta SQL evitando concatenar tanto con el punto, de hecho eso fue lo que cuasó el error de sintaxis en la consulta. Cuando usas comillas dobles, puedes poner comillas simples dentro de la cadena completa sin romperla. Así el código queda más claro. Decir sobre la consulta que si `id_Empleado` es de tipo numérico, no necesitas rodear `$cod` de comillas simples.
2. Usar una convención de nombre más estándar y menos verbosa. Para referirte a la conexión puedes usar simplemente `$db` y para una instrucción SQL puedes usar simplemente `$sql` (como hacen la mayoría de frameworks).
3. Recomendaría que uses consultas preparadas. Tu código actual es vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*.